# How to get into each element in a nested list and compare it with the equivalent in all elements in another list?

Tags: python

I need to get into each element in a nested list and compare it with the equivalent in all elements in another list.

I have two nested lists:

LB=
[[1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0]]

LK=
[[1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0]
]

Analysis flow:
I take the first sublist from LK (i.e., [1, 0, 1, 0]) and compare its individual elements (i.e., 1, 0, 1, 0) with subsequent elements from the sublists LB [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], and [0, 0, 1, 0].
I then take the second sublist from LK (i.e., [0, 0, 1, 1]) and compare its individual elements (i.e., 0, 0, 1, 1) with the subsequent elements from the LB sublist [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], and [0, 0, 1, 0]
I then take the third sublist from LK (i.e., [1, 1, 1, 1]) and compare its individual elements (i.e., 1, 1, 1, 1) with the subsequent elements from the LB sublist [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], and [0, 0, 1, 0]

Here is my attempt at the code, but I know it doesn't work properly and doesn't contain all the conditions.

```
for i in LK, LB:
    for j in i:
        while j < (len(LK)-1):
            if j == 0:
                j += 1
            elif j != 0:
                i += 1
            else:
                print(LB[i])
```

Additional conditions:

- if a given element in a list in LK is equal to 0 and the digit at the same position in LB is also equal to 0 then proceed to compare the next digit in the given list. When you get to the end of the sublist in the LK list, i.e. you pass [1, 0, 1, 0] and the condition with zeroes is fulfilled, write me this element from the LB list
- if given element in the list in LK is equal 0, but digit in the same position in the list LB is not equal 0 then skip this case and check another sublist from LB
- if there is no element 0 in the list LK (list [1, 1, 1, 1]) then write a sublist from LB

We perform such an iteration for all the elements in the list LB comparing them with the sublists from LK.

In the analyzed example during the comparison:

- the first sublist from LK ([1, 0, 1, 0]) => should be extracted from the list LB: [1, 0, 1, 0] and [0, 0, 1, 0]
- the second sublist from LK ([0, 0, 1, 1]) => should be printed from the list LB: [0, 0, 1, 0]
- the third sublist from LK ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) => should be printed from the lists LB: [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1] and [0, 0, 1, 0]
- the fourth sublist from LK ([0, 0, 1, 0]) => should be printed from the list LB: [0, 0, 1, 0]
- the fifth sublist from LK ([1, 1, 0, 0]) => no element should be written out from the list LB
- sixth sublist from LK ([0, 0, 0, 0]) => no element should be written out from the list LB

Output:
Displayed LB sublists that meet the conditions (LB sublists can be displayed in several sectors)

Comment: It's unclear what you want the final output to be. Do you just want to print each of those matching lists when you find them? Or are you trying to build a nested list: `[[[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]], [[0, 0, 1, 0]], [[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]], [[0, 0, 1, 0]], [], []]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly but it works.   Saw no good way to code your matching conditions.

Iterate though LK,  for each LK iterate through LB.   print if the list "match"

```
LB=[[1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0]]

LK=[[1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0] ]

def mch(str1,str2):
    x=0
    while x+1 < len(str1)    
        if str1[x] == 0:    
            if not str2[x]  == 0:  # 0 not in both strings
                 return False    
            if x < (len(str1)-1):  #if both strins are 0 possible match only
                                   # if strings match at next position
                                   # only do check if there is a next position
                if str1[x+1] == str2[x+1]:  
                    x+=1
                else:
                    return False     
        x+=1            
    return True



for str1 in LK:
    print("\n\n","Matches for ", str1, "\n")
    for str2 in LB:
        if mch(str1,str2)
             print(str2)
```

Comment: Thank you @William so much for your help so far! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to what exactly you want output, but if you just want to output which lists are equal, this is easily accomplished without needing to iterate through each element:

```
for lk_row_index, lk_row in enumerate(LK):
    for lr_row_index, lr_row in enumerate(LR):
        if lk_row != lr_row:
            print(f"LR row {lr_row_index} is not equal to LK row {lk_row_index}")
        else:
            print(f"LR row {lr_row_index} is equal to LK row {lk_row_index}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Peter M Not quite what I had in mind but thanks so much for your help anyway!

Comment: @MartaStolarz ah sorry. I hope you got it all figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you want to do if a sublist from LK matches more than one sublist from LB, but if you only one copy, then I think this does what you want:

```
[B_list for B_list in LB if any( 
    all(
        k_item!=0 or b_item==0 for k_item, b_item in zip(B_list, K_list)
        )
    for K_list in LK    
    )
]
```

Line 1 iterates over LB and Line 5 iterates over LK. Line 3 checks whether the corresponding elements of the chosen sublists match at a particular location, and Line 2 checks whether they match throughout the sublists. Then the `any` at the end of Line 1 checks whether, for a particular sublist of LB, there is any sublist of LK that works. So this returns all sublists of LB for which there is any sublist of LK for which for all locations the corresponding elements match.

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: It seems that they want all "matching" lists, not just one, when multiple would work.

Comment: @CrazyChucky My uncertainty is, if a sublist from LB matches more than one sublist from LK, whether they want a copy of that sublist from LB for each sublist in LK that it matches.

Comment: @Acccumulation is right, I want a sublist from LB to be copied if it matches several sublists from LK. Thank you so much for your help so far!